Как добавить код из carinput в cardriver, так чтобы он заменил класс Player и осталась коллизия и слежение за камерой
СARINPUT
import pygame, sys

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('data/fr1.png')
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (640, 360))
        self.angle = 0
        self.rotation_speed = 1.9
        self.direction = 0
        self.forward = pygame.math.Vector2(0,-1)
        self.active = False

    def set_rotation(self):
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.angle -= self.rotation_speed
        if self.direction == -1:
            self.angle += self.rotation_speed

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.original_image,self.angle,1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

    def get_rotation(self):
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.forward.rotate_ip(self.rotation_speed)
        if self.direction == -1:
            self.forward.rotate_ip(-self.rotation_speed)

    def accelerate(self):
        if self.active:
            self.rect.center += self.forward * 5

    def update(self):
        self.set_rotation()
        self.get_rotation()
        self.accelerate()


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bg_track = pygame.image.load('data/wer.jpg' )

car = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(Car())

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d: car.sprite.direction += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: car.sprite.direction -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w: car.sprite.active = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d: car.sprite.direction -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: car.sprite.direction += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w: car.sprite.active = False

    screen.blit(bg_track,(0,0))
    car.draw(screen)
    car.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)

CARDRIVER
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.key.set_repeat(200, 70)
FPS = 60
WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080
title = "CarDriver"
pygame.display.set_caption(title)

def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    # Загрузка спрайтов и их подправка размера
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error as message:
        print('Cannot load image:', name)
        raise SystemExit(message)
    image = image.convert_alpha()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    if name == 'wall1.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'roof.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'roof1.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'water.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'floor.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'floor0.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'Rock.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'Rock1.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'Rock2.png':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    if name == 'grass.jpg':
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (64, 64))
    for i in range(1, 7):
        if name == 'fr1.png':
            image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (45, 75))
    return image


def load_level(filename):
    filename = "data/" + filename
    with open(filename, 'r') as mapFile:
        level_map = [line.strip() for line in mapFile]
    max_width = max(map(len, level_map))
    return list(map(lambda x: x.ljust(max_width, '.'), level_map))  # там где нет знаков будет печатать точки

def generate_level(level):
    new_player, x, y = None, None, None
    walls = []
    global gl_spisok
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            # Текстуры дорог
            if level[y][x] == '.':
                Tile('empty', x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == '|':
                Rock = Tile('Rock', x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == ',':
                Rock1 = Tile('Rock1', x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == '-':
                Rock2 = Tile('Rock2', x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == 't':
                grass = Tile('grass', x, y)
#Дома и вода
            elif level[y][x] == 'd':
                wall3 = Tile('wall3', x, y)
                walls.append(wall3)
            elif level[y][x] == '#':
                roof1 = Tile('roof1', x, y)
                walls.append(roof1)
            elif level[y][x] == 'q':
                water = Tile('water1', x, y)
                walls.append(water)
            elif level[y][x] == 'w':
                water = Tile('water', x, y)
                walls.append(water)
#NPC
            elif level[y][x] == '!':
                Tile('empty', x, y)

#Player
            elif level[y][x] == 'x':
                Tile('empty', x, y)
                new_player = Player(x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == 'e':
                Tile('empty', x, y)
            elif level[y][x] == 'h':
                Tile('empty', x, y)
    return new_player, x, y, pygame.sprite.Group(walls)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = None
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
tiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

tile_images = {'roof1': load_image('roof1.png'),
               'empty': load_image('floor.png'),
               'water': load_image('water.png'),
               'Rock': load_image('Rock.png'),
               'Rock1': load_image('Rock1.png'),
               'Rock2': load_image('Rock2.png'),
               'grass': load_image('grass.jpg')}
tile_width, tile_height = 64, 64


class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tile_type, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__(tiles_group, all_sprites)
        self.image = tile_images[tile_type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(tile_width * pos_x, tile_height * pos_y)
        # Создаем тело объекта и раставляем спрайт на карте
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__(player_group, all_sprites)
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 7):
            self.images.append(load_image(f'fr{str(i)}.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(tile_width * pos_x + 15, tile_height * pos_y + 5)
        self.speed = 30
        self.alive = True

    def get_position(self, obstacles):
        if self.x_vel:
            self.check_collisions((self.x_vel, 0), 0, obstacles)
        if self.y_vel:
            self.check_collisions((0, self.y_vel), 1, obstacles)

    def check_keys(self, keys):
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0
        if self.alive:
            if keys == pygame.K_LEFT or keys == pygame.K_a:
                self.x_vel -= self.speed
                self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.index], True, False)
            if keys == pygame.K_RIGHT or keys == pygame.K_d:
                self.x_vel += self.speed
            if keys == pygame.K_UP or keys == pygame.K_w:
                self.y_vel -= self.speed
            if keys == pygame.K_DOWN or keys == pygame.K_s:
                self.y_vel += self.speed

    def update(self, obstacles, keys):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.check_keys(keys)
        self.get_position(obstacles)

    def check_collisions(self, offset, index, obstacles):
        self.rect[index] += offset[index]
        while pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, obstacles):
            self.rect[index] += (1 if offset[index] < 0 else -1)

class Watch_camera:
    def __init__(self, field_size):
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.field_size = field_size

    def apply(self, obj):
        obj.rect.x += self.dx
        if obj.rect.x < -obj.rect.width:
            obj.rect.x += (self.field_size[0] + 1) * obj.rect.width
        if obj.rect.x >= (self.field_size[0]) * obj.rect.width:
            obj.rect.x += -obj.rect.width * (1 + self.field_size[0])
        obj.rect.y += self.dy
        if obj.rect.y < -obj.rect.height:
            obj.rect.y += (self.field_size[1] + 1) * obj.rect.height
        if obj.rect.y >= (self.field_size[1]) * obj.rect.height:
            obj.rect.y += -obj.rect.height * (1 + self.field_size[1])

    def update(self, target):
        self.dx = -(target.rect.x + target.rect.w // 2 - WIDTH // 2)
        self.dy = -(target.rect.y + target.rect.h // 2 - HEIGHT // 2)


def lev1():
    player, level_x, level_y, obstacle = generate_level(load_level("lv1.txt"))
    camera = Watch_camera((level_x, level_y))
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                player.update(obstacle, event.key)
        camera.update(player)
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            camera.apply(sprite)
        tiles_group.draw(screen)
        if player.alive:
            player_group.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

lev1()

